# input field text entry gets sluggish when many background elements are present (and more) in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

[Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates what I describe below](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/2xr0chrp/8/)

I've been trying to track down a weird Edge rendering issue. I have not been able to reproduce the problem, but I have been able to reproduce some odd behavior that I think is directly related. I've got a background trick I use on some full pages and some page headers that involves creating a bunch of random `<div>` elements with very low opacity (that is, almost transparent) and then randomly transforming them around. It's sort-of dumb but it's been working for me without any issue in Firefox and Chrome for a while.

I recently started testing in Edge (general testing; nothing specific about the background, which I don't spend any time thinking about normally), and very soon noticed that, randomly, mousing over things with simple `:hover` style shifts (like, darkening button background color) would cause a nearly-opaque gray box to show up covering the element. The gray box would stick around for an unpredictable amount of time, and then go away randomly. It happened sometimes on just a few elements on the page, and sometimes not at all.

That as you can imagine has been making me crazy, partly because I cannot reproduce it in a CodePen or JSFiddle. While trying to investigate, I started noticing that typing into an input field on one affected page (the login page in fact) was extremely sluggish. I'm using a VirtualBox VM for this (not a factor, I don't think, as a coworker with native Windows 10 sees exactly the same problems) so I originally thought it was just latency through that, but after a while it became clear that it wasn't.

On one of several attempts to randomly change something to see what was going on, I disabled the random `<div>` background, and both the gray box problem and the sluggish input problem went away.

The fiddle linked above is a little simpler than the real setup, but not much. It's simple markup:

```
<div class=container>
    <input>
    <br>
    <button class=toggle>Toggle Background</button>
</div>
```

and then some CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.shape {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
}
.noshapes .shape {
    display: none;
}
```

The JavaScript to make the shapes is also simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
    $("<div/>", {
        "class": "shape",
        css: {
            transform: "translate(" + Math.random() * 1000 + "px, " + Math.random() * 1000 + "px)",
            opacity: Math.random() * 5 / 100,
            height: Math.random() * 200 + "px",
            width: Math.random() * 200 + "px"
        }
    }).prependTo("body");
}
```

(On my real page, I only make about 100 random elements.)

On Firefox and Chrome, the input box is completely unaffected by the presence (or absence) of the background elements. However, in Edge, there's a distinct lag when typing into the input field when the elements are visible. It's as if the renderer is trying to do some sort of collision calculation as it updates the `<input>` display as the value changes.

I wish I could reproduce the even weirder gray box problem, but I haven't been successful. It's clearly a rendering bug, much like many I've seen over the years with predecessor IE in that the manifestation involves a lot of randomness, and seemingly uninteresting events (like the window losing focus, or random mouse movements even) trigger changes. It's a little odd that Edge would suffer from such an issue, but then maybe not. (Does Edge still have the weird "hasLayout" thing?)

I'll probably end up just sniffing for Edge (which seems really sad) because I can't think of any "feature detect" approach for the problem.

Anybody else seen this?  I haven't found mention of it so far.

*edit* I think I see the slow input issue in IE11, but I cannot reproduce the gray box problem there.

Comment: I do notice in the fiddle that when I mouse over the "Toggle Background" button in Edge, it's noticeably slower to change the background color of the button when the background stuff is visible than when it's hidden. It's subtle.

Comment: @Pointy Could you open a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/ie?

Comment: @Pointy could you provide the version of Edge you are using? I'm on 20.10240.16384.0 and I can't reproduce the bug with your JSFiddle

Comment: @CalvT That's the same version. For reasons I haven't figured out, the effect is more noticeable on the actual site I'm working on. The effect is noticeable if you compare the response when you hold a key down on your keyboard, and compare when that background is shown or not.

Comment: @CharlesMorris-MSFT no, I can't - I have learned to avoid having an active Microsoft Network account because in my experience it makes logging in to my work-related OWA account even more fragile and weird than it already is. Feel free to link to my fiddle if you want to log the issue of course.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that I am seeing the same behavior.

My first thought was that the problem stemmed from the shear number of elements with unique style attributes, but curiously, the problem seems to be related to the `div`s overlapping with the `input`.

If you adjust the code so that the elements come afterwards, the problem goes away entirely.

```js
var b = document.body;
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "shape";
  div.style.transform = "translate(" + Math.random() * 1000 + "px, " + Math.random() * 1000 + "px)";
  div.style.opacity = Math.random() * 5 / 100;
  div.style.height = Math.random() * 200 + "px";
  div.style.width = Math.random() * 200 + "px";
  b.appendChild(div);
}
document.querySelector(".toggle").onclick = function() {
  document.body.className = document.body.className == "noshapes" ? "" : "noshapes";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}
.noshapes .shape {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <input>
  <br>
  <button class=toggle>Toggle Background</button>
</div>
```

I believe to avoid the problem but retain the visual layout, you might be able to modify your logic for determining the translation and height/width pixels to prevent the elements from intersecting with your container.

Comment: That makes sense, given my experience with the phenomenon. In the actual page, there are far fewer of the decorative elements, but they definitely overlap the input field. Unfortunately, the whole point is for them to be a decorative background, so overlapping the input is actually desirable. Thanks for looking at the issue though!!

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if you'd see different behavior drawing the background using a canvas instead of creating and decorating divs.

Comment: Doing it with a canvas is on my list of things to try; it's not important enough currently to worry much about it.